# Looping and appending text to StringBuilder issue

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, stringbuilder

I have a small issue when trying to append text from a loop into a stringbuilder, after trying a few things out, i think i'm on the right track with this.

**Code:**

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // STRING VALUE IT SO WE CAN REUSE //
    string action = e.Argument as string;

    // CONNECTION //
    if (action == "wraith_create_project")
    {

        // STRING BUILDER //
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // VARS //
        var articleSource = "";

        // INVOKE - AVOID CROSS THREAD ERRORS //
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { articleSource = comboBoxArticleSources.Text; }));

        // TRY/CATCH //
        try
        {
            // INVOKE - AVOID CROSS THREAD ERRORS //
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Creating project ... " + txtBoxProjectName.Text); }));

            // ARTICLE SOURCE //
            if (articleSource == "Internal Article Builder")
            {

                // VARS/CONSTANTS //
                var separator             = Environment.NewLine;
                const string gsaSeparator = "\x01";

                // WHICH SPINNER TO USE //
                if (chkBoxInternalSpinner.Checked) {

                    // LOOP //
                    var title = "";
                    var body  = "";
                    var hash  = "";
                    //var gsaArticleInfo = "";

                    for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++ ) {

                        // EVERY LOOP REQUESTS AN ARTICLE //
                        var requestArticles = Helpers.getArticleTitleAndBodyInternalSpinner("https://www.wraithseo.com/api.php?articleBuilder=1&q=" + txtBoxScrapeKeyword.Text.Replace(" ", "_"));

                        title = Helpers.internalSpinner(requestArticles.Item1); // SEND TO INTERNAL SPINNER FOR SPINNING ...
                        body  = Helpers.internalSpinner(requestArticles.Item2); // SEND TO INTERNAL SPINNER FOR SPINNING ...
                        hash  = To32BitFnv1aHash(body).ToString("X8");

                        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                        {
                            listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Returned article ... " + requestArticles.Item1);
                            listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Spun the article ... " + title);
                        }));

                        // ENCODE WITH THE GSA SEPERATOR BETWEEN EACH FIELD //
                        var gsaArticleInfo = title + gsaSeparator + "%first_paragraph-article%"  + gsaSeparator + body + gsaSeparator + hash;

                        // ADD TO THE RICHTEXTBOX ALL FIELDS FROM ABOVE //
                        var richTextBoxText = string.Join(separator, gsaArticleInfo);

                        // APPEND FIELDS TO THE STRINGBUILDER //
                        sb.Append(richTextBoxText);

                    }

                    // INVOKE - AVOID CROSS THREAD ERRORS //
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { richTxtBoxArticle.Text = sb.ToString(); }));

                } 

            } else if (articleSource == "") {
                   // RESERVED FOR ADDITIONAL SOURCES //                    
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Helpers.returnMessage(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm doing here is sending a request to my server which is returning an article sized bunch of text, i'm then spinning that text and trying to display it in a richTextBox, i noticed that instead of adding each article to the richTextBox it was being overwritten by the same article, i thought by using the stringbuilder to append the article to it on each loop i could then display it outside the loop but it always seems to overwrite, instead of adding 5 articles (which is the max i have set for tetsing)

Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated Code:**

```
    private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        string action = e.Argument as string;

        if (action == "wraith_create_project")
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            var separator = Environment.NewLine;
            const string gsaSeparator = "\x01";

            var articleSource = "";
            var title = "";
            var body = "";
            var hash = "";
            var gsaArticleInfo = "";
            var richTextBoxText = "";

            // TEST //
            List<string> gsaStuff = new List<string>();
            // TEST //

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { articleSource = comboBoxArticleSources.Text; }));

            try
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Creating project ... " + txtBoxProjectName.Text); }));

                if (articleSource == "Internal Article Builder")
                {

                    if (chkBoxInternalSpinner.Checked) {

                        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++ ) {

                            // EVERY LOOP REQUESTS AN ARTICLE WHICH IS RETURNED AT RAND() //
                            var requestArticles = Helpers.getArticleTitleAndBodyInternalSpinner("https://www.wraithseo.com/api.php?articleBuilder=1&q=" + txtBoxScrapeKeyword.Text.Replace(" ", "_"));

                            title = Helpers.internalSpinner(requestArticles.Item1); // SEND TO INTERNAL SPINNER FOR SPINNING ...
                            body  = Helpers.internalSpinner(requestArticles.Item2); // SEND TO INTERNAL SPINNER FOR SPINNING ...
                            hash  = To32BitFnv1aHash(body).ToString("X8");

                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Returned article ... " + requestArticles.Item1);
                                listBoxMain.Items.Add("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Spun the article ... " + title);
                            }));

                            // ENCODE WITH THE GSA SEPERATOR BETWEEN EACH FIELD //
                            gsaArticleInfo = title + gsaSeparator + "%first_paragraph-article%"  + gsaSeparator + body + gsaSeparator + hash;

                            // ADD TO THE RICHTEXTBOX ALL FIELDS FROM ABOVE //
                            richTextBoxText = string.Join(separator, gsaArticleInfo);

                            // APPEND FIELDS TO THE STRINGBUILDER //
                            sb.Append(string.Join(separator, gsaArticleInfo));

                            gsaStuff.Add(richTextBoxText);

                            // INVOKE - AVOID CROSS THREAD ERRORS //
                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { richTxtBoxArticle.AppendText(richTextBoxText); }));
                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { richTxtBoxArticle.Lines = gsaStuff.ToArray(); }));

                        } // End for loop.

                        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { richTxtBoxArticle.Lines = gsaStuff.ToArray(); }));
                        //Helpers.returnMessage("SB Contents: > " + sb.ToString());

                    } // End checkbox.

                } else if (articleSource == "") {
                       // RESERVED FOR ADDITIONAL SOURCES //                    
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Helpers.returnMessage(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it as simple as `richTxtBoxArticle.Text +=` instead of `=`?

Comment: I'm not seeing how the article retrieved in your `for` loop would vary in each iteration; you're not using `x` anywhere.  Should the URL passed to `Helpers.getArticleTitleAndBodyInternalSpinner()` change?  Perhaps different values for your `articleBuilder` query parameter instead of fixing it at `1`?

Comment: Do one thing to make your life easier as a coder - never write `catch (Exception ex)`. You should only catch **specific exceptions** that you can **meaningfully handle**. If you're just logging errors then you are hiding bugs and making it very hard to get your code 100% correct.

Comment: You also can't call `chkBoxInternalSpinner.Checked` or `txtBoxScrapeKeyword.Text` inside your background worker without calling them on `.Invoke`. You cannot safely create, update, and also read any UI control from a non-UI thread.

Comment: I have updated the OP with some more things i have tried, this is a strange one, `richTxtBoxArticle.Text +=` does not seem to work neither does `richTxtBoxArticle.AppendText(richTextBoxText);` it keeps overwriting the richTextBox content rather than appending to it, i even tried a `List<string> gsaStuff = new List<string>();` the same output, it's always overwritten, the URL sends a request to a server, the server will return a random article (making it unique each time) i can see in my logs it does this, which is the intent.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about `txtBoxScrapeKeyword.Text` this should be invoked, but on testing the software reads the input keyword fine (whci it shouldn't as it isn't invoked) this is a good surprise in a way :) but i will fix this, thank you for the try / catch advice this is noted from now on :) i'm stuck on what else to try to add each `string.Join(separator, gsaArticleInfo);` to the richTextBox, this is all saved to a file so it needs to be in there, i will keep debugging and post back. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're calling onto the UI thread from another thread REALLY QUICKLY.  The textbox simply can't keep up.

The solution here is to use the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method, and pass the strings back out of your worker to your UI thread.  You'd handle the `ProgressChanged` event of the worker from your Form, and update your controls within there instead.

Hope that helps you out.